# Using and multiplying arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**I have a set of tasks i have to complete please help me im stuck on the multiplication one :(**

*1. np.array([0,5,10]) will create an array of integers starting at 0, finishing at 10, with step 5. Use a different command to create the same array automatically.*

```
array_a = np.linspace(0,10,5)
print array_a
```

**Is this correct? Also what is meant by automatically?**

*2. Create (automatically, not using np.array!) another array that contains 3 equally-spaced floating point numbers starting at 2.5 and finishing at 3.5.*

```
array_b = np.linspace(2.5,3.5,3,)
print array_b
```

1. Use the multiplication operator * to multiply the two arrays together

**How do i multiply them? I get an error that they arent the same shape, so do i need to slice array a?**

Comment: Why the downvote? Looks like an understandable question to me.

Comment: I guess because its too "homeworky"

Comment: Asking homeworks is supposed to be perfectly acceptable here. As long as you're clear about what are you asking, and you are capable of understanding the answer. He didn't ask for an answer for his homework.

Comment: sorry guys, this IS homework, but im not just fishing for answers, i AM actually trying. 
Ive edited because while i was waiting for an answer i thought maybe i can slice array_a to only use the first 3 values to multiply with array_b but that just seems wrong... '-_-

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first problem is wrong; it asks you to create an array with elements `[0, 5, 10]`. When I run your code it prints `[  0. ,   2.5,   5. ,   7.5,  10. ]` instead. I don't want to give the answer away completely (it *is* homework after all), but try looking up the docs for the `arange` function. You can solve #1 with either `linspace` or `arange` (you'll have to tweak the parameters either way), but I think the `arange` function is more suited to the specific wording of the question.

Once you've got #1 returning the correct result, the error in #3 should go away because the arrays will both have length 3 (i.e. they'll have the same shape).

Comment: I really dont understand. When it specifies 'in 5 steps' that means i have to produce 5 elements in the array doesnt it? :( ive been at this for hours, feel like such an idiot.

Comment: Easy misunderstanding - a 'step' is the distance between items in a sequence. To create a sequence using a step, you have some starting value and then you repeatedly add the step to it to create the next value, until you're done. So in the array `[0, 5, 10]` you start at 0 (per the question), then keep adding 5 ('with step 5') until you get to 10 (inclusive, apparently). The question doesn't specify 3 items explicitly, but that's how many times you can add 5 to 0 without being >10.

Comment: so it would actually be np.linspace(0,10,3) which would provide an even space of 5 between each step, or more likely np.arange(0,15,5) which WILL output an array ending at 10, start at 0 and have "step 5"?
Man the wording in the proffs questions could not be more confusing, this isnt the first time. she tries to use slang and relate to the students in lectures. :/ and cartoons everywhere possible....

Comment: P.s. i dont know who downvoted you, but i really appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think anyone downvoted this question - 0 is the default as far as I can tell (got downvoted in something else but that was because my code had a bug). Best of luck with the class!